# Python adding a list to a CSV file in column format (not rows)

Tags: python, list, csv

```
with open('APEC.html', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f)
    for row in reader:
        pass

with open('APEC.html') as f:
    Model = [row for row in f if row.startswith('A')]

with open('APEC.html') as f:
    Pad_Shoe = [row for row in f if row.startswith('P')]

with open('APEC.html') as f:
    Kit_Lead = [row for row in f if row.startswith('K')]

with open('APEC.html') as f:
    Disc_Drum = [row for row in f if row.startswith('D')]

with open('APEC.html') as f:
    Year = [row for row in f if row.startswith('0')]

with open('APEC.html') as f:
    C1top = [row for row in f if row.startswith('Model')]

with open('APEC.html') as f:
    C2top = [row for row in f if row.startswith('Year')]

with open('APEC.html') as f:
    C3top = [row for row in f if row.startswith('Pad / Shoe')]

with open('APEC.html') as f:
    C4top = [row for row in f if row.startswith('Kit / Lead')]

with open('APEC.html') as f:
    C5top = [row for row in f if row.startswith('Disc / Drum')]

with open('APEC.html') as f:
    C6top = [row for row in f if row.startswith('Adj Bar')]




c1 =  (C1top, Model)
c2 = (C2top, Year)
c3 = (C3top, Pad_Shoe)
c4 = (C4top, Kit_Lead)
c5 = (C5top, Disc_Drum)
c6 = (C3top, Pad_Shoe)
c7 = (C4top)
c8 = (C6top)
c9 = (C5top, Disc_Drum)

for nth, (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9) in enumerate(zip(c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9)):
    pass

file = open("Table.csv", "w")
for items in c1:
    file.write([items,])
```

> Opening a Html file with the data i need
>
> Extracting the data from the html file and search each row starting with 'x'
>
> Setting Variables
>
> Ziping them all together
>
> Opening the file and trying to add the items above
>
> Any one tell me where im going wrong or tell me how to add all the variables above into a CSV file (columns not rows)

Syntax :

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):   File
 "C:\Users\B8\Desktop\Task\writing_to_columns.py", line 67, in <module>
     file.write([items,]) TypeError: must be str, not list
```

Comment: which line is 67? if last then is that comma needed?

Comment: error after taking coma away               TypeError: must be str, not list

Comment: it would be  `file.write(srt([items]))` if you wanted to actually write the list as a list to the file but there are easier ways, what do you want the row to actually look like in your file?

Comment: Take away the brackets

Comment: @PadraicCunningham                 file.write(str[items])
TypeError: 'type' object is not subscriptable

Comment: @PadraicCunningham            for each variables data to be in a column :/ thats what im stuck with i know how to write into rowns but not into columns and writing a list to a file

Comment: add an example of what c1 looks like

Comment: print(c1) >>>>>  (['Model\n'], ['A1 [2010-]\n'])

Comment: `f1.writelines(items)`

Comment: that works but when i open the CSV file it says this is read only this file cannot be edited

Comment: have you changed the file from read-only in excel? You could also use try os.chmod https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod

Comment: it says its been locked by 'another user'

Comment: just read through the docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.chmod and do not understand it could you explain ?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham  i realise i didn't .close the file thanks for all your help though !

Comment: No worries, that would make sense from locked by 'another user'

Comment: quick question @PadraicCunningham how do i select which column i want because if i write all the variable they all overwrite each other and go into the first column

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be under a number of misapprehensions (for instance, that you can treat a file containing HTML as if it contains CSV data), but the issue most directly addressing your question is your notion that you can write CSV files in columns rather than rows.

CSV files *are not* inherently columnar, notwithstanding that they are often used in a limited way (with the same number of items in each row) that is relatively easy to interpret as columns.  CSV files are sequentially written, newline-separate collections of values with commas separating each value and each value optionally enclosed in a quoting character (often the ASCII double-quote character).

There is no requirement in CSV that each line have the same number of values.

There is no way in reading or writing CSV to directly address any row without first reading the preceding rows in the file.

There is no way in reading or writing CSV to address a value in a row without parsing the row and decoding all the values.

Therefore, any exercise in writing a CSV file necessarily involves writing one row at a time, in sequential order and writing all values on that row, again in sequential order.  If you have a CSV file and want to change the 10th value in row 9,542 you must read the entire file, change the value, and write out the file again.